# Get all records where each words in string exists on any of the columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am building a search functionality and need help with a postgres query. My use case is - When a string is an input, what is the best (optimized) way in postgres to get all records where each words in string exists on any of the columns in a table ?

**Sample Table: (The table I am working with has 40 columns)**

| FName | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| John | Engineer |
| Carlos | Doctor |

**Case 1:** Given a string 'John Doctor',  In this case it would return both the records.

**Output:**

| FName | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| John | Engineer |
| Carlos | Doctor |

**Case 2:** Given a string 'John Engineer', it would only return 1 row

**Output:**

| FName | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| John | Engineer |

**Case 3:** Given a string 'Carlos', it would return 1 row

**Output:**

| FName | Occupation |
| --- | --- |
| Carlos | Doctor |

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to do following:

```
SELECT FName, Occupation
FROM yourtable
WHERE 
'John' IN (FName, Occupation) OR
'Doctor' IN (FName, Occupation);
```

I don't know if this is already a sufficient answer for you because it's unclear if the logic to fetch the different names from your "search string" must be written as SQL query, too. I think that's a much better task for your application.

If this must also be done in pure SQL, you could use `UNNEST` to split your string.
Something like this:

```
WITH sub AS
(SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY('John Doctor', ' ')) AS searchNames)
SELECT 
DISTINCT y.FName, y.Occupation 
FROM yourtable y, sub 
WHERE
sub.searchNames IN (y.FName, y.Occupation);
```

This will split your string by spaces into the different names, i.e. you need to provide a search string in the form you have mentioned, with a space between the names.
This will produce the correct results according to your description.

We can verify this here: [db<>fiddle1](https://dbfiddle.uk/77EgA9Fv)

This can be extended for as many column as needed. Let's for example add a further column `col` and search `Test3` in this column, then the query will be like this:

```
SELECT FName, Occupation,col
FROM yourtable
WHERE 'John' IN (FName, Occupation, col)
OR 'Doctor' IN (FName, Occupation, col)
OR 'Test3' IN (FName, Occupation, col);
```

Or again with `UNNEST` like this:

```
WITH sub AS
(SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY('John Doctor Test3', ' ')) AS searchNames)
SELECT 
DISTINCT y.FName, y.Occupation, y.col 
FROM yourtable y, sub 
WHERE
sub.searchNames IN (y.FName, y.Occupation, y.col);
```

Try this here: [db<>fiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/ASEFUxA1)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your response. Do you know if there is anyway we can incorporate a like operator with %<input_string>% within the IN clause? For example - if we have "Jo" as an input it would still return the record

Comment: As far as I know, there is no simple and short way to do this, you would need to write out all these conditions or to create an own function you can call for that. SQL is generally bad in such things and I highly recommend to avoid this. It's not only complicated to write, but multiple likes can also extremely slow down your query. It would be much better to think about which exact strings chould be checked and keep using the = operator or an in clause.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regexp match operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) (case insensitive) and `any` to find the records that contain at least one of the words in the list.

```sql
select * 
from the_table t
where t::text ~* any(string_to_array(the_words_list, ' '));
```

DB Fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gCNX2wX9peX21rbyTrkNsX/0)

Comment: Thank you! Using regexp match, is anyway we can incorporate a like operator with %<input_string>% within the IN clause? For example - if we have "Jo" as an input it would still return the record with John

Comment: You could use ILIKE with ANY, it would be the same but more difficult as you have to put every array element within % signs